# Set period only after very last bib-item in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

My university has some special format-rules for the bibliography:

The bib-items have no period at the end.
Only the VERY LAST one has to end with a period!

This is how it should look like:
[image])

I changed the finentrypoint with `\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}` - that works fine.
But how do I get the period after the very last entry then??

I use biber.

Does any one have suggestions for me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Every day we learn new peculiar formatting rules. ;-) I can find no sense in such a direction, do you? You have all my sympathy.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what style you use. Ideally, you would post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` to include the final period. Note that this will most likely cause problems with empty bibliographies.

Keep `\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}`.

Take the definition of `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` and add `\addperiod` to the line reading `{\endlist}`, so it reads `{\addperiod\endlist}`. You can find the definition of `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` in the `.bbx` file to your bibliography style.

For `numeric` that is

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\addperiod\endlist}%<---- here
  {\item}
```

For `authoryear` it's

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\addperiod\endlist}%<---- here
  {\item}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\addperiod\endlist}%<---- here
  {\item}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{wilde,cicero,knuth:ct:a}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: moewe, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!! It work´s perfect. Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

The output of the bibliography is done done inside an environment defined by

```
% {<name>}{<start code>}[<end code>]{<item code>}

\newrobustcmd*{\defbibenvironment}[4]{%
  \long\csdef{blx@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{blx@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{blx@item@#1}{#4}}
```

Every style uses this definition of modify the environment. So for your needs you have to make sure that the final period is set at `blx@endenv@#1`.  This can be globally achieved by:

```
\cspreto{blx@endenv@bibliography}{\addperiod}
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
\cspreto{blx@endenv@bibliography}{\addperiod}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion,knuth:ct:a,angenendt}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]